# How to use arguments passed from bash script in html

Tags: html, bash, perl

I am passing the values from perl/bash script to below html code, to get it print like below.

```
Top_Heading 1 : One
Middle_Heading 2 : two
```

where value of $heading_1 is Top_Heading 1  and  $Value1 is One and similar to heading 2

Passing the value as below in perl script.

```
my $heading_1 = $ARGV[0];
my $Value1 = $ARGV[1];
my $heading_2 = $ARGV[2];
my $Value1 = $ARGV[3];



<tr>
        <td><b> <TMPL_VAR NAME= heading_1> :</b> <TMPL_VAR NAME= Value1> </td>

</tr>
<tr>
        <td><b> <TMPL_VAR NAME= heading_2> :</b> <TMPL_VAR NAME= value2> </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: What is a "perl/bash" script? This looks like you are just asking for a Perl script that outputs a particular fragment of HTML given the four arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use [HTML::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template). But I only knew that because I recognised the syntax in your HTML snippet. In the future, you should probably include important information like that in your question.

The documentation for this module (linked above) is pretty good. I've never used the module myself, but after skimming the documentation, I was able to write this simple demonstration program (which is based on your requirements).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Template;

@ARGV == 4
  or die "Not enough arguments\n";

my ($heading1, $value1, $heading2, $value2) = @ARGV;

my $template = <<EO_HTML;
<tr>
        <td><b> <TMPL_VAR NAME=heading_1> :</b> <TMPL_VAR NAME=Value1> </td>

</tr>
<tr>
        <td><b> <TMPL_VAR NAME=heading_2> :</b> <TMPL_VAR NAME=value2> </td>

</tr>
EO_HTML

my $ht = HTML::Template->new(scalarref => \$template);

$ht->param(
  heading_1 => $heading1,
  Value1    => $value1,
  heading_2 => $heading2,
  Value2    => $value2,
);

print $ht->output;
```